Is a logistic regression appropriate for my question and correctly interpreted?
I need help knowing if my statistical approach is correct for what I want to achieve.
I want to know whether a trial that follows an error (i.e., has a post.error value of 1) makes it more likely that the next trial is also an error (i.e., the following trial accuracy would be = 1) and I wanted to know whether the pressure_block also had an effect (where pressure_block = 1 is low pressure and pressure_block = 2 is high pressure).
To address this I build a dummy dataset here.
# Load necessary library
library(dplyr)

# Create the data
id <- rep(1:5, each = 200)  # 5 people, 200 rows per person (100 rows per block)
pressure_block <- rep(rep(1:2, each = 100), times = 5)  # 2 blocks, 100 rows per block, repeated for each person
trial <- rep(1:100, times = 10)  # Trial counter, 100 rows per block, repeated for 10 blocks

# Combine into a dataframe
df <- data.frame(id, pressure_block, trial)

# Add accuracy vector (randomly generated binary vector for simplicity)
set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
df$accuracy <- sample(0:1, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

# Add error vector (0 = accuracy being right, 1 = accuracy being wrong)
df <- df %>% mutate(error = ifelse(accuracy == 1, 0, 1))

# Add post.error vector
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id, pressure_block) %>%
  mutate(post.error = lag(error, default = 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

I believe I want to use a logistic regression here to answer my question. We can run this with the data above like so
model <- glm(accuracy ~ post.error, family = 'binomial', data = df)

Then I get the summary of my model.
summary(model)

which shows me:
Call:
glm(formula = accuracy ~ post.error, family = "binomial", data = df)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.03622    0.08973   0.404    0.686
post.error  -0.11977    0.12656  -0.946    0.344

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1386.2  on 999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1385.3  on 998  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1389.3

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

Now back to the question:
Is this an appropriate statistical approach for this question?
Does the output suggest that post.error does not significantly predict accuracy (p = .344)?
Does the coefficient -.12 suggest the log-odds? That is, when the predictor is = 1 the log-odds of an error (or correct response?) is -.12?
Finally, I want to add pressure_block variable:
model2 <- glm(accuracy ~ post.error * pressure_block, family = 'binomial',
              data = df)
summary(model2)

And we get the following output
Call:
glm(formula = accuracy ~ post.error * pressure_block, family = "binomial", 
    data = df)

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                0.02690    0.28605   0.094    0.925
post.error                -0.47220    0.40101  -1.178    0.239
pressure_block             0.00616    0.17952   0.034    0.973
post.error:pressure_block  0.23690    0.25342   0.935    0.350

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1386.2  on 999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1383.4  on 996  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1391.4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

Here the questions are the same as above:
Is this test appropriate?
All predictors are non-sig (p > .05)?
Do the coefficients refer to log-odds?
Thank you for your time with this and for any response you can give. I have a real dataset that may give extra insights if more context is needed.
Best wishes,

Yes, you could use the logistic regression, but I find a simple contingency table much more intuitive.
ftable(df[, c("pressure_block", "post.error", "accuracy")])

#                          accuracy   0   1
#pressure_block post.error                 
#1              0                   119 123
#               1                   142 116
#2              0                   125 130
#               1                   120 125
#

chisq.test(ftable(df[, c("pressure_block", "post.error", "accuracy")]))

#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
#
#data:  ftable(df[, c("pressure_block", "post.error", "accuracy")])
#X-squared = 2.7427, df = 3, p-value = 0.433

p >0.05 thus one should not reject the null hypothesis.

Thanks for this reply and for your time. I agree this looks much simpler. Can I ask, for my own understanding in general, are my interpretations of the other questions I pose (not just is the logistic regression appropriate) also correct? I am fairly happy with interpreting p values but mainly what the coefficients show?

Also, how could you factor in the 3rd variable of pressure to this chi square / contingency approach?

I see the edits - thanks again

Sorry I updated above with ftable() to handle the third variable.  To answers your questions, yes the logistic regression is fine, I think it is more difficult to understand. Yes all of the predictors are not significant.  You can use the coefficients in the logistic regression to find the probability of success.  See the predict() function.

Thanks a lot Dave - this is helpful :)

I don't think that this answer (or the model proposed in the question) handles correlations within the 5 individuals who each have 200 observations. Although this approach might work with this simple set of synthetic data, it could cause problems in a real-world experiment when the 1000 observations are no longer independent due to correlations of outcomes within individuals.

How could we be considerate of these correlations? And factor them in to any analyses?

@jbrimm2004 try a mixed binomial (e.g., logistic) regression, withid as the basis for random effects around your fixed effects. The simplest random effects allow for individual differences in the intercept (log-odds at reference conditions), thus taking intra-individual correlations into account. You might have enough data to allow for random slopes with respect to one or more of your fixed effects, too, if you think that's appropriate. See this UCLA web page, or many on this site; try our search function.

@EdM thanks again for the feedback and your time. I tried a mixed binomial with the real data (using id as a random effect) and tbh a lot of the outcome values were the same. I think that I just need to work out which is more appropriate for the data and the question in mind.

@jbrimm2004 the point estimates of regression coefficients might not be much different with a mixed model, but the standard errors (and thus significance tests) could well be. It depends on the nature of the intra-individual correlations. At the least, you will have trouble trying to publish your results if you don't take the intra-individual correlations into account.
